# How to solve this polynomial word problem?

Tags: polynomials

It's probably easy for a lot of you, just a question in my book I couldn't understand, can anyone explain how will we do this step by step. Thanks!

Given that $2x^2 + 3px -2q$ and $x^2 + q$ have a common factor $x - a$ where $p$, $q$ and $a$ are non-zero constants, show that $9p^2 + 16q = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both polynomials have a common factor of $x - a$, we know that both polynomials have $x = a$ as an $x$-intercept. Thus:
\begin{align*}
2a^2 + 3pa - 2q &= 0 \\
a^2 + q &= 0
\end{align*}
But since $a^2 = -q$, substituting into the first equation yields:
\begin{align*}
2(-q) + 3pa - 2q &= 0 \\
3pa &= 4q \\
9p^2a^2 &= 16q^2 \\
9p^2(-q) &= 16q^2 \\
-9p^2 &= 16q &\text{since } q \neq 0\\
9p^2 + 16q &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, thanks! Perfectly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x-a$ is a common factor, we have
$$2a^2+3pa-2q=0,\ \ \ a^2+q=0.$$
Since $a^2=-q$, we have
$$2(-q)+3pa-2q=0\Rightarrow 3pa=4q\Rightarrow a=\frac{4q}{3p}.$$
Hence, $a^2=-q\Rightarrow \left(\frac{4q}{3p}\right)^2=-q\Rightarrow 16q^2=-9p^2q\Rightarrow 16q=-9p^2\Rightarrow 16q+9p^2=0.$

Answer (score 0):

We have: $2a^{2}+3pa-2q=0$ and $a^{2}+q=0$, hence $4a^{2}+3pa=0$.

Then $9p^{2}a^{2}=16a^{4}=-16qa^{2}$ leading to $9p^{2}+16q=0$ (since $a\neq 0$).